# php arrays : How to convert array to string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
[Code] => Array
    0 => array (
        [Nom] => NameVille
        [CodeI] => 38
    )
    1 => array (
        [Nom] => NameVille2
        [CodeI] => 39
    )
```

And i want  to print data like this :

Name : NameVille, NameVille2

Code : 38,39

how can i do that ? thankss

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Use foreach then inside foreach implode their value. :D This is just a hint. You must write the code in order for you to learn not copy paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php

  $array = [
     ['Nom'=>'NameVille','CodeI'=> 38],
     ['Nom'=>'NameVille2','CodeI'=> 39],
  ];
 $name = "";
 $code = "";
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
     $name .= $value['Nom'] . ", ";
     $code .= $value['CodeI'] . ", ";
 }

 echo "Name :".$name;
 echo "code :".$code;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_column` & `implode` together.

```
echo implode(',', array_column($your_array, 'Nom'));
echo implode(',', array_column($your_array, 'CodeI'));
```

[Check Demo](https://eval.in/433271)

`array_column` will return an `array` with the values in that column. And `implode` will concatenate them with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(function($element){return $element['Nom'];}, $arr));
echo join(', ', array_map(function($element){return $element['CodeI'];}, $arr));
```